How do I enqueue interactivity.js on my own (PHP)-template in TwentyTwentyThree theme?
I am building a site with the TwentyTwentyThree theme and I am using PHP templates for some pages and CPTs. But on these pages interactivity.js is not enqueued. Alas, the mobile nav is not working.
<script type="importmap" id="wp-importmap">
{"imports":{"@wordpress\/interactivity":"http:\/.../interactivity.js?ver=6.5.2"}}
</script>
<script type="module" src=".../wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view.js?ver=6.5.2" id="@wordpress/block-library/navigation-js-module"></script>
<link rel="modulepreload" href=...t/wp-includes/js/dist/interactivity.js?ver=6.5.2" id="@wordpress/interactivity-js-modulepreload">

These scripts are missing on pages with custom templates. (website url removed)
The js should be enqueued automatically but it does not.I can add the links manually to the template and it works but there must be a more elegant way to do this by calling a WP function, I guess.
Any help is appreciated.
